# PDFBox - “no main manifest attribute”

Tags: java, powershell, pdfbox

I'm trying to run pdfbox in powershell, but I just get the error:

```
java -jar .\pdfbox-2.0.14.jar ExtractText '.\TEST.PDF' out.txt
no main manifest attribute in pdfbox-2.0.14.jar
```

Same with pdfbox-tools-2.0.14.jar:

```
java -jar .\pdfbox-tools-2.0.14.jar ExtractText '.\TEST.PDF' out.txt
no main manifest attribute in pdfbox-tools-2.0.14.jar
```

Java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)
```

Comment: the tools jar doesn't have a main.

Answer (score 1):

try pdfbox-app-2.0.8.jar, it works for me (version is not that important).

```
usr>java -jar C:\Users\Dominique\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Twago\pdf2csv\dist\lib\pdfbox-app-2.0.8.jar
PDFBox version: "2.0.8"
Usage: java -jar pdfbox-app-x.y.z.jar <command> <args..>

Possible commands are:
  ConvertColorspace
  Decrypt
  Encrypt
  ExtractText
  ExtractImages
  OverlayPDF
  PrintPDF
  PDFDebugger
  PDFMerger
  PDFReader
  PDFSplit
  PDFToImage
  TextToPDF
  WriteDecodedDoc

usr>
```

Comment: Nevertheless, you should update. By updating, you show that you value the work of the PDFBox developers and the users who contributed bugfixes / improvements.